# Remove "ipv6only" option from Puppet nginx module

Tags: nginx, ipv6, puppet, vhost

My nginx server (which serves multiple vhosts) fails to start:

```
Nov 08 23:54:43 foo systemd[1]: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
Nov 08 23:54:43 foo nginx[3830]: nginx: [emerg] duplicate listen options for [::]:8081 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/000-mysite.vhost:3
Nov 08 23:54:43 foo nginx[3830]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Nov 08 23:54:43 foo systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 08 23:54:43 foo systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.
Nov 08 23:54:43 foo systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Nov 08 23:54:43 foo systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
```

I've pinpointed the problem to two `listen` directives bound to the same TCP port for both IPv4 and IPv6, where the option `ipv6only` is used:

```
[root@foo ~]# head /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.vhost 
server {
        listen 8081;
        listen [::]:8081 ipv6only=on;  
        ssl off;
...
```

So this configuration works correctly:

```
[root@foo ~]# head /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.vhost 
server {
        listen 8081;
        listen [::]:8081;  
        ssl off;
...
```

[Related question: https://serverfault.com/questions/638367/do-you-need-separate-ipv4-and-ipv6-listen-directives-in-nginx]

Now, this configuration is provisioned by Puppet via the [puppet-nginx module](https://travis-ci.org/voxpupuli/puppet-nginx).  Is there a way to (via Puppet) not specify the `ipv6only` option, or solve the problem in another manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to say, how your puppet part looks like. Anyway, puppet-nginx module has resource `nginx::resource::vhost`, which - I guess - you use somehow. This resource has option `ipv6_listen_options`, which [includes ipv6only=on by default](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-nginx/blob/master/manifests/resource/vhost.pp#L212). So you should be able to call it in this way:

```
nginx::resource::vhost { 'example.com':
    ipv6_listen_options => '',
    # another options there
}
```

Another possibility is that you use older module, which had `ipv6only=on` hardcoded in template. It was fixed in Feb with [this pull request](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-nginx/pull/249). So you can remove it from template or upgrade module.